# Why does my Ender 5 Pro bed stop heating 10 °C below the set point?

Tags: heated-bed, creality-ender-5, temperature

After a long battle with SKR Mini v2, TFT35 and BLTouch and creating the right firmware. I thought I was through it all and ready to start printing again after finally being able to set the Z offset and auto level the bed. My printer has other thoughts. Now my bed temperature will only heat up to 10 °C below the set point temperature and after a few minutes it starts beeping and says this on the screen "`Heating Failed: Bed Printer Halted, Please Reset`". As an example, set it to 60 °C, it will get up to 50 °C normally and stop at 50 °C.

Anyone gone through this? I'm sure there is some setting in the firmware that I have missed up. I'm hoping someone can educate me on my mistake.

Answer (score 2):

Searching the error message "Heating Failed: Bed Printer Halted, Please Reset" seems to indicate that the bed heater is timing out from not reaching temperature.

1. If you measure the voltage applied to the bed heater before the error message, does the voltage stay at Max.; i.e. 12 V for a 12 V bed heater?  Or, does the voltage stay constant?
2. If you raise the target bed temperature, does is still error out at stop at 50 °C?
3. Since you only indicate changing firmware, we would assume the bed heater is the same as when previously working.  Is this true?
4. Is the resistance of the bed heater a few ohms and not megaohms?

Answer (score 1):

I was having the same issue after installing BTT SKR Mini E3 V2 and BLTouch on my Ender 5 Pro.

I did two things and my bed heats normally now, but I changed/did both things and can't say which fixed the issue for me.

- I noticed the case fan wasn't coming on. I had it plugged into `Fan 1` on the board. In my Marlin firmware, I noticed in `Configuration_adv.h` the `USE_CONTROLLER_FAN` was commented out, so I enabled it (removed the '//' in front of `#define USE_CONTROLLER_FAN`). After I flashed the firmware with this change, the controller box fan did start kicking on as I'd expect.
- I also did PID tuning on the bed. The firmware I'd compiled had the `PIDTEMPBED` enabled as I prefer to tune the bed when I do the hotend too. I hadn't yet tuned the bed when I was getting the 10-degree heating failure. My bed was set to 60 °C and it wouldn't heat above 52 °C without giving the "Heating Failed: Bed Printer Halted, Please Reset". After PID tuning (which I did after the fan firmware change too) the bed heats up to 60 °C and stays there now.